# Почему компонент не получает (не имеет) props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Имеется такой простой (лишнее специально вырезал) компонент:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class QueryParamSelect extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(this.props)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default QueryParamSelect;
```

Вывожу его в шаблон back-end фреймворка следующим образом:

```
%QueryParamSelect{ label: 'Label', options: @options, param: 'rts' }
```

Что в итоге эквивалентно этому:

```
<queryparamselect label="Label" options="[[&quot;all&quot;, &quot;All&quot;], [&quot;first&quot;, &quot;First&quot;], [&quot;second&quot;, &quot;Second&quot;]]" param="rts"></queryparamselect>
```

Ну и чтобы все это дело заработало использую это:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (document.getElementById('query-param-select')) {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <QueryParamSelect/>,
      document.getElementById('query-param-select')
    )
  }
})
```

В итоге я получаю `{}` от `this.props`.

Глядя на официальную документацию (https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) я не совсем понимаю в чем проблема. Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить где и что я сделал не так?

Comment: вы в `ReactDom.render` передаете компонент, куда не прокидываете ни какие `props`, откуда же им взяться?

Comment: @ThisMan думал что можно описывать только тег. А как тогда описать в `ReactDom.render`? Сделал так: `<QueryParamSelect label="" options={[]} param=""></QueryParamSelect>`, но в итоге игнорируется то, что прописывал в шаблоне back-end фреймворка...

Comment: вы скорее всего не правильно используете бэкенд фреймворк. В любом случае, именно в `ReactDOM.render` должен передаваться компонент с пропсами

Comment: @ThisMan смотрите, идея такая - есть back-end фреймворк со своими шаблонами и прочим. Вот на одной из страниц хочу сделать динамику - добавить компонент React. Соответственно, прописал `<queryparamselect (...)></queryparamselect> на строне back-end'а в его шаблоне. Ну и уже в JS файле с помощью `ReactDOM.render` хотел его "оживить". Согласен что скорее всего делаю что-то не так, но не вижу как сделать правильно :(

Comment: @ThisMan насколько я понимаю в моем коде выше делается следующее - находим элемент `#query-param-select`, удаляем его содержимое и вставляем внутрь него `<QueryParamSelect label="" options={[]} param=""></QueryParamSelect>` компонент. А нужно судя по всему просто найти элемент, найти и "оживить" React компоненты внутри него. (Надеюсь понятно описал)

Comment: похоже не совсем понимаете, как именно работает `React`

Comment: @ThisMan добавил ответ. Не знаю насколько корректен вариант, но на текущий момент он работоспособен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Весь код я привел к такому виду и все заработало.

На стороне back-end фреймворка:

```
#query-param-select{ 'data-label': 'Label', 'data-options': @options, 'data-param': 'rts' }
```

В JS:

```
const qps = document.getElementById('query-param-select')
ReactDOM.render(<QueryParamSelect label={qps.dataset.label} options={qps.dataset.options} param={qps.dataset.param} />, qps)
```

В React компоненте ничего не трогал.